# How to put arbitrary widgets into a gtk.Menu?

Tags: python, menu, gtk, pygtk

How can any gtk.Widget (eg. a progress bar) be put into a gtk.Menu as one of the menu items?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting from the [PyGTK documentation](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtkmenuitem.html):

> The gtk.MenuItem and its derived
>   widget subclasses are the only valid
>   children of menus.

So the answer is: You can't.  But:

> As a gtk.MenuItem is a subclass of gtk.Bin it can hold any valid child widget.

If you create a MenuItem without a label:

```
item = gtk.MenuItem()
```

you can add most `gtk.Widget` subclasses as a child to `item`.