# displaying calendar in a combox drop-down menu

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I would like to be able to select a date from a calendar in a combobox.
The answer given here [Showing a gtk.Calendar in a menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132929/showing-a-gtk-calendar-in-a-menu) doesn't satisfy me since it seems possible to do it better using a custom cell renderer as shown there: http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq13.056.htp 
but i'm not able to use the renderer correctly.

The code below shows you what i have, but it just gives a combobox with nothing in it and no drop-down menu.

Do i have to connect a combobox signal to the do_start_editing function from the CellRendererDate class? (and then how?) or what is missing?

```
class MyWindow(gtk.Window):

....

  liststore=gtk.ListStore(str)
  cell=CellRendererDate()
  cell.set_property('editable',True)
  combo=gtk.ComboBox(liststore)
  combo.pack_start(cell, True)
  combo.add_attribute(cell, 'text', 0)

....

class CellRendererDate(gtk.CellRendererText): # code from the pygtk FAQ, linked above

  __gtype_name__ = 'CellRendererDate'

  def __init__(self):
    gtk.CellRendererText.__init__(self)
    self.date_format = '%d/%m/%Y'
    self.calendar_window = None
    self.calendar = None

  def _create_calendar(self, treeview):
    self.calendar_window = gtk.Dialog(parent=treeview.get_toplevel())
    self.calendar_window.action_area.hide()
    self.calendar_window.set_decorated(False)
    self.calendar_window.set_property('skip-taskbar-hint', True)

    self.calendar = gtk.Calendar()
    self.calendar.display_options(gtk.CALENDAR_SHOW_DAY_NAMES | gtk.CALENDAR_SHOW_HEADING)
    self.calendar.connect('day-selected-double-click', self._day_selected, None)
    self.calendar.connect('key-press-event', self._day_selected)
    self.calendar.connect('focus-out-event', self._selection_cancelled)
    self.calendar_window.set_transient_for(None) # cancel the modality of dialog
    self.calendar_window.vbox.pack_start(self.calendar)

    # necessary for getting the (width, height) of calendar_window
    self.calendar.show()
    self.calendar_window.realize()

  def do_start_editing(self, event, treeview, path, background_area, cell_area, flags):
    if not self.get_property('editable'):
      return

    if not self.calendar_window:
      self._create_calendar(treeview)

    # select cell's previously stored date if any exists - or today
    if self.get_property('text'):
      date = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.get_property('text'), self.date_format)
    else:
      date = datetime.datetime.today()
      self.calendar.freeze() # prevent flicker
      (year, month, day) = (date.year, date.month - 1, date.day) # datetime's month starts from one
      self.calendar.select_month(int(month), int(year))
      self.calendar.select_day(int(day))
      self.calendar.thaw()

      # position the popup below the edited cell (and try hard to keep the popup within the toplevel window)
      (tree_x, tree_y) = treeview.get_bin_window().get_origin()
      (tree_w, tree_h) = treeview.window.get_geometry()[2:4]
      (calendar_w, calendar_h) = self.calendar_window.window.get_geometry()[2:4]
      x = tree_x + min(cell_area.x, tree_w - calendar_w + treeview.get_visible_rect().x)
      y = tree_y + min(cell_area.y, tree_h - calendar_h + treeview.get_visible_rect().y)
      self.calendar_window.move(x, y)

      response = self.calendar_window.run()
      if response == gtk.RESPONSE_OK:
        (year, month, day) = self.calendar.get_date()
        date = datetime.date(year, month + 1, day).strftime (self.date_format) # gtk.Calendar's month starts from zero
        self.emit('edited', path, date)
        self.calendar_window.hide()
      return None # don't return any editable, our gtk.Dialog did the work already

  def _day_selected(self, calendar, event):
    # event == None for day selected via doubleclick
    if not event or event.type == gtk.gdk.KEY_PRESS and gtk.gdk.keyval_name(event.keyval) == 'Return':
      self.calendar_window.response(gtk.RESPONSE_OK)
        return True

  def _selection_cancelled(self, calendar, event):
    self.calendar_window.response(gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL)
    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

Check Kiwi's DateEntry:

http://doc.stoq.com.br/api/kiwi/_modules/kiwi/ui/dateentry.html